# What does "on-premise" mean when referring to istio or kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm new to istio, and I read istio docs(https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#istio-identity):

> Istio service identities on different platforms:
>
> 1. Kubernetes: Kubernetes service account
> 2. GKE/GCE: may use GCP service account
> 3. GCP: GCP service account
> 4. AWS: AWS IAM user/role account
> 5. On-premises (non-Kubernetes): user account, custom service account, service name, Istio service account, or GCP service account. The custom service account refers to the existing service account just like the identities that the customer’s Identity Directory manages.

I can't make it clear what does `on-premise` mean? Can anyone give me some more detailed information about `on-premise`? And how does it compared to `kubernetes`?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess "on-premise non-kubernetes" would be something around Consul, since this is the only non-k8s setup that I know of istio: https://istio.io/docs/setup/consul/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"On Premises" simply means locally at your organization in contrast to remote / in the cloud. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-premises_software